# Filter in excel skips names, why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have strange problem while updating excel workbooks for consultants. It looks like filtering is not working correctly as it's not always picks up the consultant name from the `wsTarget` to filter `wbSource`.

I'm really dazzled as it's works for some names and it doesn't for others. I double checked and the names are the same in `wsTarget` and `wsSource`.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub CopyToWorkbooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsConsultant As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim cons As Range

    strPath = "xxx"
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

    Set wsSource = Workbooks("JobsOn.xlsm").Worksheets("TOCOPY")

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx*")

    Do Until strFile = ""
        If strFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
            Set wsTarget = wbtarget.Worksheets("Revenue Tracker")
            Set cons = wbtarget.Worksheets("Revenue Tracker").Range("C1")

            wsSource.Range("$A$1:$F$10000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=cons

            wsTarget.Unprotect Password:="xxx"

            On Error Resume Next

            wsSource.Range("B2:B37").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsSource.Range("C2:C37").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsSource.Range("D2:D37").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            'wsSource.Range("F2:F37").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            'wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wsSource.Range("A2:A37").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            wsTarget.Columns.AutoFit

            wsTarget.Protect Password:="jayne", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            wbtarget.Save
            wbtarget.Close

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            wsSource.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If

        strFile = Dir()
    Loop

    Worksheets("UNIQUE").Range("A2:F100000").FormatConditions.Delete
    Worksheets("UNIQUE").Range("G2:G100000").Clear

    wsSource.Range("A2:F10000").Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try removing `On Error Resume Next` to make sure you're not getting an error?

Comment: If you step through with `F8`, can you determine where the issue occurs?  (Also, instead of copy/pasting just values, set ranges equal to eachother. This skips using the clipboard and may make it more efficient.  `Range([destination range]).Value = Range([values to copy range]).Value`.)

Comment: I feel like `strFile = Dir()` would throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, in other words, I'm having trouble understanding the loop. It seems to me that this would be an infinite loop. Won't there be an error at `strFile = Dir()`, so `strFile`'s value wouldn't change and therefore it just keeps on looping since strFile never equals ""?

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero - `Dir()` returns an empty string once all files in a folder have been enumerated.

Comment: @dwirony when I remove this part it won't complete the loop. When consultant is in the spreadsheet it will ask me to save new spreadsheet and I don't want it, I just want overwrite it. This part will just skip the open spreadsheet.

Comment: Try making sure any existing filtering is removed before you apply the filter you need on ColE

Comment: Please ignore `strPath = "xxx"` as I have removed the string for the GDPR reasons.

Comment: @wisniadj Are you saying you're using that line to avoid a certain error? I'm not sure what you mean with *"This part will just skip the open spreadsheet."*.

Comment: `It looks like filtering is not working correctly as it's not always picks up the consultant name from the wsTarget to filter wbSource.` Ensure that consultant name does not have any leading or trailing spaces... "wisniadj" is not the same as "   wisniadj   "

Comment: Try this for me `Criteria1:="=*" & cons.Value & "*"` If this works then that means there are leading/trailing spaces or unprintable characters :) And yes... try vice versa as well.. Maybe `cons.Value` has leading/trailing space? `Criteria1:=Trim(cons.Value)`

Comment: @dwirony I need to overdrive the spreadsheet which is in shared network. It may happen that the workbook is open by consultant and when running the macro it asks me to create consultantsname1.xlsx and it stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution... Silly me...

```
Range("B2:B37")
```

This part has caused all the confusion. There were more rows to copy and that is why only some has been copied. I simply change the range from `Range("B2:B37")` to `Range("B2:B10000")` and all is working perfectly

Thank you @BruceWayne for the suggestion with using F8. That helped!